# Freemarker remove white space between html tags except for one macro

Tags: freemarker

I have a html which has regular html tags with contents and then a user added custom content. I want to remove the white spaces between the html tags in the regular content but do not remove any white spaces between the tags in the user added custom content.
Custom content are embedded part of <#macro>
Here is an example of ftl:

People.ftl

```
<#macro people>
 <#include "address.ftl">
</#macro>
```

Address.ftl

```
...
....
<#macro>
  <div class="custom content">
 ${.node.@@text}
</div>
</#macro>
...
....
```

In the address.ftl there are other text/nodes added

Current HTML output I get.

```
<div> <div> <p>From Address.ftl</p> </div> <div> <p>From Address.ftl</p> </div>
<div class="custom content"> <p>From macro Address.ftl. I have white space between sub tags <sub> </sub> like this </p> </div> </div>
```

Expectation:

```
<div><div><p>From Address.ftl</p></div><div><p>From Address.ftl</p></div>
<div class="custom content"> <p>From macro Address.ftl. I have white space between sub tags <sub> </sub> like this </p> </div></div>
```

The whitespace between the html tags need to be removed but do not remove any white spaces between html tags within the macro which outputs
`<div class="custom content"> <p>From macro Address.ftl. I have white space between sub tags <sub> </sub> like this </p> </div>`

Used a <#compress> on the output this removes all unnecessary white spaces leaving single white space between the tags including the content within the macro. Then I had to replace any white space between the tags for the entire content which affects the content within the macro as well

Comment: could you try to paste your code and desired html output in a way that is more readable? It is hard to understand your problem without the example. ;)
(try refering to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if needed)

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear. Have updated my post.

Comment: I am seeing some info about using the t tag for all trim, lt to ignore leading trim, and rt to ignore the trailing trim.